# Vlookup with IF

Tags: excel, excel-formula

One table is a list of package types with allowed weight and charges:

So I have:
Parcel Name 
Exact Parcel Type
Min Allowed Weight
Max Allowed Weight
Standard fee EU> UK 
Promotional fee EU > UK

as per image:

[parcel list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CueNg.png)

then I have a table that contains: 
productid, parcelname, weight
SKU123, ExtraLargeEnvelope, 459,99

For each product id I need to extract the appropriate promotional fee eu>uk and I would do that by matching parcel names in both columns and finding the row where weight falls between min allowed weight and max allowed weight. How do I do that in excel ?

If it makes it any clearer I was able to achieve that in mysql with the following query:

```
    SELECT 
    p.sku, p.asin, efn.exact_parcel_type, efn.promotionalfeeeuuk
FROM
    products p
        JOIN
    efneuuk efn ON p.product_size_weight_band = efn.parcel_name
WHERE
    p.item_package_weight BETWEEN efn.minallowedweight AND efn.maxallowedweight
GROUP BY p.sku;
```

Comment: Just a remark: an SQL-command like `SELECT ... WHERE ... BETWEEN ... AND ...` yields multiple results. A `VLookup()` only one.

Comment: You do not have `ExtraLargeEnvelope` in you given example picture. Post data as text so that we can copy.

Comment: Also what is your excel version.

Comment: Does the function have to look for a match in both, the parcel name and the weight? or does one always imply the other?

Comment: @Harun24hr I don't really know how to paste the data here so it keeps it's structure, but what I have given is just an example. You can substitute ExtraLargeEnvelope for StandardEnvelope.

Comment: @DattelKlauber Sort of... The function needs to match parcel name as this is the only exact connection. However in the parcel list table each parcel name will have several instance with different min and max weight, so to return value from the right row the function then needs to compare weight with min and max weights.

Comment: Sounds like this could be solved with the `FILTER()` function if your excel version allows for it. You would set it up as `FILTER(fee_range,(name_range=name)*(min_weight_range<=weight)*(max_weight_range>=weight))` where `name` and `weight` are the input parameters to filter by.

Comment: It could also be done with the `SUMIFS()` function if the specification can only have one result.